# Operator not working !=

Tags: javascript, if-statement, operators, operand

My code has this

```
 if (choice != 'A1' || 'A2' || 'A3' || 'B1' || 'B2' || 'B3' || 'C1' || 'C2' || 'C3'){//dosomethingrecursive}
```

Whenever I choose say, 'A1', it acts as if that is choice is not = to it. which as I understand is wrong, or am I missing something?

Comment: What do you think 'A2' cast to a Boolean would be?

Comment: That's not how things work in JavaScript. You have to explicitly make the comparison with each possible value.

Comment: I have no idea what that means

Comment: `if (choice != 'A1' && choice != 'A2' && choice != 'A3' ... )`

Comment: Really Pointy, wouldn't that just be so much more code?

Comment: Yes, you are missing something. ;) You should read the JavaScript documentation regarding how to do boolean expressions. They don't work that way. And, yes, it's more code the way Pointy shows it, but it's correct code. Shorter code is no good if it's not correct.

Comment: Ahhh, cheers, I'll give that a go!

Comment: Yes, it's more code.  You could take a completely different approach. What you've got is syntactically correct but it absolutely will not do what you think it will.

Comment: @Bartholomew it is so much more code, but it's valid code, unlike what you have. Typically if you have a giant statement like this, you're better off reconditioning the logic for easier typing

Comment: you're evaluating `choice != 'A1'`, and then evaluating `A2`. `A2` evaluates to `true`.  You're not evaluating `choice != 'A2'`, etc.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll give your advice a try. I'll read that up

Comment: Pointy, your advice worked. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript and in all programming languages I know, boolean [logic operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) don't combine in that way, they follow a fixed `bool OPERATOR bool` schema.

This means that your series of parenthesised `||` is first incrementally converted to one single value, and that value is then compared with your `choice`.

The easiest way to achieve the logic you want is by harnessing [Array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to repeat your logical operation on each of your values until the operation fails:

```
['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'].every(function(x) { x != choice })
```

Which translates to: `'choice' must be different from every value in 'array'`.

In general everytime you need to repeat something, think about how you could do it with arrays and their [iterator methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods), it's often the most elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write it like that.
If you don't want to (correctly) chain tests

```
if (choice != 'A1' && choice != 'A2' && ...
```

and want something shorter, you could put your values in an array, and test that `choice` is not an element of the array:

```
[ 'A1', 'A2', ... ].indexOf( choice ) < 0
```

Comment: `choice` is not a string, it's a variable :)

Comment: @PDKnight `choice` is not a string ? How do you know ?

Comment: change `.indexOf("choice")` to `.indexOf(choice)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't translate an English sentence into code like this - the meaning of the code is more precise, and in this case different.

Your code calculates

```
'A1' || 'A2' || 'A3' || 'B1' || 'B2' || 'B3' || 'C1' || 'C2' || 'C3'
```

and then compares the result to `choice`.  This is not what you want.

You have to do the comparisons individually, e.g.

```
if (choice != 'A1') && (choice != 'A2') && ...
```

Comment: Almost. It's evaluating `choice != 'A1'`, then the rest. Your conclusion is correct though.